# How to add a custom block as a usual "product" to shop page / archive-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking for a possibility to add a custom html block/post to the woocommerce "shop page" inside the products grid, as a product.

What I mean.. I have a grid of products on the "shop" page (archive-product) and I want to create a special post/page/html block with some text information, that will be inserted into the products grid as a one of "product", but with no price, with no title and unclickable. I've attached the screenshot of the final result I want to have, it's really self explaining - [here it is exactly what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdjdV.jpg).

As an idea probably I can create a special product with specific slug or title and the corresponding  script with pre_get_posts hook will find this post/product and modify it to look like I need. I'm looking for some code/ideas how to insert this specific block/page/post into the archive-product page on some position in the grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Previous code was wrong, changed it here

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{
    if ($i == 2) {
        echo "Cusom block";
    }
    echo "<p> Product block " . $row['column'] . " </p>";
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got the idea, and it looks like a right direction, but i'm not sure that my development level is enough to implement it.. I'm looking for some snippet, that I could add to probably content-product.php or do_action with some hook to do your idea with echo "Custom block" instead of "Product block".. I need something more specific for wordpress files, but the idea is clear. Thanks!

Comment: I did it :) Thanks to the direction you've pointed! So thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help, guys! I've implemented the functionality I was looking for. I've found the corresponding loop in archive-product.php and as was suggested by JapanGuy, I've added a simple "if i equal let's say 5 then echo < li>[Custom block]< /li>" .

The original snippet from archive-product.php:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

Modified code with inserted custom block:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php                                   
          if ($i == 5) {
          echo "<li>[Custom block]</li>";
          }
          $i++; 
        ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

Im such simple way I can add any content to the created [Custom block] and have an usual products grid with extra custom designed block. I'm not very experienced programmer, so probably my code is not perfect, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creating WordPress Custom Post Archives : Hope this meets your requirement.

Custom Post Archives list your custom content. You probably already know the standard WordPress archives. So you can follow this to display both together .

Ref here : https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-wordpress-custom-post-archives/

Comment: Thanks for reference, it could be helpful.. I will dig it.